# React navigation drawer v5x useNavigation() with Component Class

Tags: react-native

I have tried many times to navigate using `useNavigation()` in my Component class. But I couldn't because according to the error I should use this method inside of a body function. I tried it inside `render()` method. It wasn't also helpful. Could you possibly help me if anyone knows?

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default class MenuDrawer extends React.Component{

render(){

const  navigation  = useNavigation();
return(
    <View>
       <Button  onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('detail')}}  />
   </View>
);

}
}
```

Comment: will you show your snippet?

Comment: As you see above I  used 'useNavgation()' inside of render().

Comment: I have to navigate in my class that there is constructor and is extended with Component.In this process I encountered the error that I have mentioned above.

Comment: You are currently using a class based component but all you need here is `functional` component. Make the change and bingo!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/use-navigation.html), you can wrap the component inside a function to use it

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default yourFunction(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <MenuDrawer navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Your new `MenuDrawer`

```
export default class MenuDrawer extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
      return(
        <View>
         <Button onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('detail')}}  />
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```